# File Writing and Reading not working Java

Tags: java, swing, file, file-io, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a simple GUI app that takes strings and a button and saves it to a file. When the app loads, the fields are populated with the values in the text file, which will look like this:
School Name
Selected Radio Button
Date

When I change the values in the GUI it will overwrite the above values in the text file. The program populates the gui fields by reading line by line.

As I have my program now it gets an array Index out of bounds exception and it does not save anything to the file.

here is the stacktrace:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at prog24178.TestingFiles.<init>(TestingFiles.java:66)
    at prog24178.TestingFiles.main(TestingFiles.java:88)
```

here is the code:

```
public class TestingFiles extends JFrame {
    private JTextField txtCollege;
    private JTextField txtDate;
    public ArrayList <School> schools;
    String file = "c:\\Temp\\schools.txt";


    public TestingFiles(){
        super("Testing Files");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        txtCollege = new JTextField();
        txtCollege.setBounds(0, 0, 359, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txtCollege);
        txtCollege.setColumns(10);

        JRadioButton selComp = new JRadioButton("Computers");
        selComp.setBounds(10, 27, 109, 23);
        getContentPane().add(selComp);

        JRadioButton selEng = new JRadioButton("Engineering");
        selEng.setBounds(139, 27, 109, 23);
        getContentPane().add(selEng);

        JRadioButton selArt = new JRadioButton("Arts");
        selArt.setBounds(281, 27, 78, 23);
        getContentPane().add(selArt);

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(selArt);bg.add(selEng);bg.add(selComp);

        txtDate = new JTextField();
        txtDate.setBounds(0, 57, 359, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txtDate);
        txtDate.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.setBounds(0, 77, 183, 34);
        getContentPane().add(btnSave);
        btnSave.addActionListener(new SaveActionHandler());

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.setBounds(183, 77, 176, 34);
        getContentPane().add(btnExit);
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ExitHandler());


        schools = new ArrayList <School>();
        try{
            File f = new File(file);
            Scanner s = new Scanner (f);
            while (s.hasNextLine()){
                String line  = s.nextLine();
                String [] fields = line.split("/n");
                //schools.add(new School(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2])); ***Array Index out of bounds
            }
            s.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){}
    }


    class SaveActionHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            schools.add(new School(txtCollege.getText(),txtDate.getText() ));
        }       
    }
    class ExitHandler implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);     
        }       
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestingFiles app = new TestingFiles();
        app.setSize(375,150);
        app.setVisible(true);
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
class School  {
    private String college;
    private String field;
    private String date;
    public School() {};
    public School(String college, String field,  String date){
        this.college = college;
        this.field = field;
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getCollege() {
        return college;
    }
    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setCollege(String college) {
        this.college = college;
    }
    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    public void setDate(String date){
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: Where is the exception? What line? Could we see a stack trace?

Comment: That's not the error you said you were getting... Fix this line: `schools.add(new School(txtCollege.getText(),txtDate.getText() ));`

Comment: fixed now, had comments there

Comment: You probably want to learn some basic debugging. You'll never need to post about runtime exceptions such as this one again if you do. Step one: find the part of the code that's causing the error. (The stack trace has a line number). Step two: look at the loop bounds and the array/list you're looping through. One of them contains an error (e.g. incorrect size, hard-coded bounds). You can also print some stuff to see what's happening.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from there. Could you give me a hint as to where to proceed?

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, I was posting from a hands that feature fat fingers...

Comment: Your first problem is using a null layout, your second is closing your resource within the try-catch block, instead of the finally block, your third is ignoring the exception that could be thrown

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
File f = new File(file);
Scanner s = new Scanner (f);
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    String line  = s.nextLine();
    String [] fields = line.split("/n");
...
```

You're getting a line from the file and then trying to split it on the newline character. `Scanner#nextLine()` by default gives you everything from its current position up to the next newline. In that case, a `String` returned by `Scanner#nextLine()` will never contain a newline, so your `fields` array will only ever contain one item, the entire `line`. So when you try to access `fields[1]` you get the exception.

An easy way you could have figured this out yourself, since you know the line that has the problem start there and work backwards to verify your assumptions. The first assumption you should verify is that `fields` contains the number of fields you expect.

```
String [] fields = line.split("/n");
System.out.println("fields contains " + fields.length + " items");
```

That would have told you that `fields` only contains one item.

The next assumption to verify would be that `line` actually contains newlines.

```
String line  = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Line is " + line);
```

Ahh, there's the problem! line doesn't contain any newlines and you're trying to split on newlines.

Comment: So i added a print statemnt and it printed my whole file as one. How can I seperate the values by line?

Comment: @user3524591 You added a print statement in the while loop and were surprised when it printed the entire file?

Comment: So where do I go from herre?

Comment: I've tried adding a delimter to the scanner to delimit a new line but that did now work

Comment: @user3524591 That's a pretty vague statement.